# Why does this code produce 'unreachable statement' error?

Tags: java, variables

The variable is already declared in the method, and I want to use the variable again, in the same method for an if else statement.This is my method and variable declared.

I get an 'unreachable statement' error.

```
public void update() {

    System.out.println("'Back' to go back.");
    System.out.println("Enter Invoice Number:");
    String code = Input.getTextInput();
    if ("back".equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
        return;
    }
    InvoiceDto invoiceToUpdate = invoiceService.readByCode(code);

    //Update the Invoice in memory
    System.out.println("Enter New Product ID:");
    String productId = Input.getTextInput();
    if ("back".equalsIgnoreCase(productId)) {
        return;
    } else {
        invoiceToUpdate.setProductId(productId);

        return;
    }

    invoiceToUpdate = invoiceService.readByCode(code);
    if (invoiceToUpdate == null) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid invoice code");

        return;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the variable? Try that.

Comment: make it a global variable

Comment: @rafid059 To use it an `else if` in the same method? Bad advice.

Comment: @rafid059 There is no such thing as a global variable in Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but looks to me that those two blocks of code are in different scopes

Comment: @EJP now your'e just messing with me. Global instance variable is a thing. Or is it not??

Comment: @rafid059 'Global instance' is a contradiction in terms. Nobody is messing with you. Cut out the personal remarks.

Comment: if you want to use it in the same method there should be no problem. or did i miss something here?

Comment: Let me guess. What you mean is - how do I go back to the `readByCode` statement to fill the same variable with the next code?

Comment: @snap, I want to use the variable in the same method, what is the syntax or how do I write it?

Comment: @EJP I know this is getting off-topic in this post, but what about public static variables? [I'm not arguing here, btw]

Comment: just use it again. so you don&#39;t need the declaration, just the assigment. so i guess:

invoiceToUpdate = invoiceService.readByCode(code);

Comment: @FathimaVariyawa You've written it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: can you give us an example of how u tried using it and had issues? You use it just by typing it.

Comment: @rafid059 They are scoped by the class they are declared in. There is no global scope in Java. `public static` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @snap it has an error 'unreachable statement'. I can post the code, but its 20 lines. Its a basic Customer Database and we updating the Invoice for user to add in invoice code.

Comment: @FathimaVariyawa you can post the relevant code lines inside your question.

Comment: You have an `if` and an `else` with a `return` in each. One of those returns must execute. The following block of code is unreachable. Your code doesn't make sense. Nothing to do with 'calling a variable'.

Comment: And, for good measure, there is no such thing as 'call a variable' in Java, and nothing about it in the error message, which is perfectly clear, and should have been included in your original post. Don't jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get an "unreachable code" error is this:

```
if ("back".equalsIgnoreCase(productId)) {
    return;
} else {
    invoiceToUpdate.setProductId(productId);

    return;
}
```

This code returns from the method in both the "if" and the "else" clauses. It means that flow will never get to the line after this `if`. Thus, you get the error.

You probably need to re-think you logic. `return` sends you back to the place in the code which called the method. The logic of your method does not make sense.